# How to write mulitple if and return statements in one line of code?

Tags: python

How do you write one line of Python Code with 3 if statements each returning a statement?
EX:

```
if ((x<c) and (c<r)):
    return c
if ((c<x) and (x<r)):
    return x
if (c<b) and (r<x)):
    return r
```

Comment: `return c if ((x<c) and (c<r) else return x if ((c<x) and (x<r)) else …`

Comment: You're looking for the ternary operator

Comment: @martineau That's not quite right. You only need the word `return` once in the statement, at the beginning. The rest is just an expression describing what you want to return.

Comment: @khelwood: Quite right…should only have the first `return`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1):

In general, **don't**: it's harder to read.  Instead, simply clear out the redundancy in your existing code:

```
if x < c < r:
    return c
elif c < x < r:
    return x
elif c < b and r < x:
    return r
```

The same redundancy elimination can fuel the one-liner, but even then, it's still a pain to read, especially with the meaningless variable names.

```
return c if x < c < r \
  else x if c < x < r \
  else r if c < b and r < x \
  else None
```

Answer (score -1):

you could do it like this:

```
c if ((x<c) and (c<r)) else x if ((c<x) and (x<r)) else r
```

Another way, propably not really practical but still possible:

```
from itertools import compress
list(compress([c, x, r], [((x<c)&(c<r)), ((c<x)&(x<r)), ((c<b)&(r<x))]))[0]
```

Answer (score -3):

Use conditional expressions. Add parentheses around the nested one to ensure proper precedence.

```
return c if (x < c and c < r) else (x if (c < x and x < r) else (r if (c < b and r < x) else None))
```

You need to make the `None` default return value explicit, since conditional expressions require both `if` and `else` expressions. This will happen if any of the values are equal, rather than strictly less than each other.

That said, I strongly recommend against this. It's not nearly as clear as your original code. There's no bonus for one-liners, except in Code Golf competitions.

It also seems like you're always returning the middle of the 3 values. So you can simply sort them and return the middle one:

```
return sorted([x, c, r])[1]
```

However, this doesn't return `None` in the case that some of the values are equal. Maybe that can't happen?